# Django Disassociating Many To Many Relationship

Tags: django-models

I am having trouble disassociating many to many relationships...

```
b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
e = Entry.objects.get(id=234)
b.entry_set.remove(e)
```

doesnt seem to work...
how do i disassociate without deleting anything?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `b.save()` after removing the entry.